# Rotation stops after spawned other node

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Cats are spawning and following to zombie.And they face looks to the zombie too,but rotation stops when other cat spawned.

```
-(void)spawningCat
{
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"cat" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){
        float actionDuration = 0.1;
        CGPoint offset = CGPointSubtract(_zombie.position, node.position);
        CGPoint direction = CGPointNormalize(offset);
        CGPoint amountToMovePerSec = CGPointMultiplyScalar(direction, CAT_MOVE_POINTS_PER_SEC);
        CGPoint amountToMove = CGPointMultiplyScalar(amountToMovePerSec, actionDuration);
        node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x+amountToMove.x, node.position.y+amountToMove.y);
        _velocityCat = CGPointMultiplyScalar(direction, CAT_MOVE_POINTS_PER_SEC);

        [self rotateNode:_cat toFace:_velocityCat rotateRadiansPerSec:CAT_ROTATE_RADIANS_PER_SEC];
    }];
}

-(void)spawnCat
{
    _cat = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"cat"];
    _cat.position = CGPointMake(ScalarRandomRange(0, self.size.width), ScalarRandomRange(0, self.size.height));
    _cat.name = @"cat";
    [self addChild:_cat];

- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    [self spawningCat];
}
```

Comment: show the _cat spawning code - I suspect since you only have once ivar named _cat you will only rotate the most recently spawned _cat instance.

Comment: I showed _cat spawn code,look at the edit

Comment: Yup, you replace _cat with the new sprite, thus self rotateNode:_cat will only rotate the most recently spawned _cat.

Comment: I dont know how can i write it. I tried
[self rotateNode:node toFace:_velocityCat rotateRadiansPerSec: CAT_ROTATE_RADIANS_PER_SEC];

Comment: Pointer wants SKSpriteNode *.But "node"  is just SKNode how can i write it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just typecast the node with SKSpriteNode and rotate it. Just as below:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"cat" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){
    SKSpriteNode *tempCat = (SKSpriteNode *) node; // typecast node
    [tempCat runAction:[SKAction rotateByAngle:1 duration:1]]; // eg: do action with 'tempCat' SKSpriteNode
}];
```

Keep Coding.............. :)